# Choosing between embeds_many and references_many in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

what are the key points that one should think of while choosing between `embeds_many` and `references_many` (or `embeds_one` and `references_one`) in Mongoid?

I'm currently preferring `embeds_many` over `references_many`, but that is resulting in too many nested `embeds_many`'ies and I'm worried that it might add unnecessary overhead to the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important thing to be aware of is the 4 MB limit for each document in MongoDB - by using references instead of embedding documents, you can keep the size of your documents lower.

Other information about the differences can be found [here](http://joeloliveira.com/2010/10/23/visualizing-the-difference-between-references_many-and-embeds_many-in-mongoid/).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should to use "entity-object" and "object-value" definitions from [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).
For entity use reference,but for "object-value" use embed document.

And check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446/value-vs-entity-objects-domain-driven-design) for more details about entity vs object-value.