# How to differentiate Entity and ValueObject?

Tags: domain-driven-design

How to differentiate *Entity* and *ValueObject*?

For my recent project using DDD, I am often confused by the two.

1. What's Entity and VO?
2. The responsibility
3. Should Entity and VO contain any logics, like date parsing, returning a bool by the fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75446/2575224

Comment: thanks for you comment

Comment: You are welcome. The difference between the two of them is largely discussed on the internet.

Comment: Well...haha. Although largely discussed on the internet, most of them are about the theory. You know how abstract is DDD. In the reality, we may come across varied issues. If we could get a wiki about best practice for DDD, that should help a lot

Comment: I know, practicing DDD is a different Beast. The only solution is, well, more practicing :) I read a lot of books and articles and what helped me was to actually write code.

Comment: @Julian please ask specific questions about specific problem instances. Then it won't be about theory ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I also wish it was an easy way of rule of thumb for determining  if your new model is `Entity` or `ValueObject`?

Personally I am using following question:

- Do I have any property in my model that history of it's changes matters?

  - if yes then my model is more likely an `Entity`
  - if no then my model is more likely a `ValueObject`

So using it in example, `Person` model depends to our domain(logic/bussiness), history of it's `FirstName` property may matters or not. if it does then `Person` is `Entity`.

In the other hand we must be able to set `updatable = false` for our `ValueObject` properties. and when update is necessary, simply we be able to delete previous record and insert new one[1].

About your other questions, I think one of the greatest thing about DDD is isolating logic into domain/model layer. "Simple POJOs which are easily testable". So feel free to add any logic into your domain/model as far as you can **unit-test** them with easy.

I hope my answer was some kind of useful and please let me know if you find something more convenient for distinguishing these two guys! :^)

[1] If `ValueObject` is in many-side of a relation, then we need to check if update is necessary for all (one-side)references or not. if not then we leave current record as it is and we insert new record(for those references that update is needed).